# Bash script to start a detached tmux session, run a script, and keep the tmux session alive

Tags: bash, shell-script, tmux

I want to write a bash script that will:

- start a new tmux session and run a script
- attach to it
- not exit after the script finishes execution

I tried this:

```
tmux new -d -s my_session '$SHELL -c " sleep 1; echo please dont exit after echo; sleep 1;"'
tmux attach -t my_session
```

But this exits after the script finishes execution. How can I keep the session alive so I can attach and execute more scripts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do one of these:

- Run a shell after the command: `tmux new -dsmy_session 'mycommand; exec $SHELL'`
- Let tmux start a shell and then type the command with `send-keys`: `tmux new -dsmy_session \; send mycommand Enter`

You could also set the `remain-on-exit` option but it is tricky to do this when you create a session with a command because the command might exit before you manage to set it.

Comment: adding `exec $SHELL` at the end did the trick! Can you explain `send-keys` though? Is that something I can write inside the shell script?

Comment: Yes you can do it like my example, tmux will send the keys as if you had typed them at the shell prompt.