# How can I introduce a pause during a tmux send-keys operation?

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux

I want to use tmux's `send-keys` to [run a series of commands when I log into a remote server](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/586424/3358)

In the linked answer, a single command is used.  I've found that I can put a series of them but I've never gotten more than 2 of them to successfully run.  Is it possible to introduce a pause between them (since I assume the problem is one of tmux executing them before the remote host can respond)?

The commands will span a change of the logged-in user, which hasn't been problem so far, but that's one reason I can't simply have a script on the server that I run.  (tmux doesn't care if I change user but a script can't do that and then continue running.)

So how can I go beyond just 2 commands?

I doubt it is relevant, but I'm running zsh locally and bash on the server.

Comment: Are you running commands like `tmux send-keys -t s1 username` from a shell script or are you binding keys? If it is a script then just use `sleep` in the script. The correct tool to do this is probably `expect` which can react to the output rather than just typing blindly.

Comment: I'm actually running functions that exist on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. This is no doubt blindingly obvious to you but we can't see what you are doing. How are you running your two commands? The linked answer gives 2 solutions. The `sendkeys`one looks like a script to me. Are you actually typing `tmux new -dmy_session \; send mycommand Enter` or do you have this in a function or in a file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand the question either, but [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) may help you.  It can send input to interactive sessions and parse responses, avoiding things like manual delays to wait for logins, commands to finish, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to write an expect script that (1) issues an SSH command, (2) selects a number at a DUO-related prompt, (3) waits for me to approve the connection in the DUO iPhone app, (4) changes user once logged into the remote host, and (5) leaves the shell open for interactive use after the expect script terminates?  I'm guessing that either step #3 or step #5 might be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a 'sleep' between the tmux commands....

```
tmux send-keys -t 1 "echo -n hello " Enter
sleep 5
tmux send-keys -t 1 "echo world" Enter
```

However the usual reason to wait is becuase something needs to happen before continuing - relying on a fixed interval is not good engineering. It would be much safer to use a proper `expect` script as @FazJaxton suggests.